# How to know when Turbo.renderStreamMessage completes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

I'm populating an empty list object

```
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

via a turbostream request

```
# myaction.turbo_stream.erb 
<%= turbo_stream.append "results" do %>
    <li data-mystimulus_target="item">HELLO WORLD</li>
<% end %>
```

I am making the request via the fetch api from a stimulus controller, and I want to interact with the new `item` targets once they have been appended to the DOM.

```
// mystimulus_controller.js
static targets = ["item"]

connect() {
    fetch(this.myRequest())
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.text()
            }
            throw response.status
        })
        .then(html => { 
            Turbo.renderStreamMessage(html)
            // immediate
            console.log("immediate has items check", this.hasItemTarget))
            // delayed
            this.delay(1000).
                then(() => console.log("delayed has items check", this.hasItemTarget))
        
            })
        .catch(error => console.warn(error))
} 

myRequest() {
    return new Request("myurl", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "text/vnd.turbo-stream.html"
        },
        redirect: "manual"
    });
}

delay(milliseconds){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
    });
}
```

`console.log("immediate has items check", this.hasItemTarget))` returns false

`console.log("delayed has items check", this.hasItemTarget))` returns true

`Turbo.renderStreamMessage` appears to be asynchronous, but after digging around I've not found any callbacks or promises exposed by this function.

Have I overlooked anything? Is there a better way to ensure that `Turbo.renderStreamMessage` has completed before proceeding (I would like to get rid of my `delay()` function).

Comment: Why are you manually sending the fetch request in the first place? Kind of defeats the whole point of Turbo.

Answer (score 0):

Turbo stream here only does a simple `append`, if you're trying to do something more complex than that, maybe a custom turbo stream action would be a better choice:

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams#custom-actions*

You can use stimulus target callbacks to know when element is inserted:

```html
<li data-mystimulus-target="item">HELLO WORLD</li>
                   ^
```

Add to stimulus controller:

```js
itemTargetConnected(target) {
  console.log(target);
}
```

*https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/targets#connected-and-disconnected-callbacks*

---

You can always add your own observer:

```js
connect() {
  this.observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList) => {
    mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
      if (mutation.type == "childList") {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
          if (node instanceof Element) {
            console.log(node);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
  this.observer.observe(this.element, { childList: true });
}

disconnect() {
  this.observer.disconnect();
}
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver*

---

Also, don't discount turbo frame, it can do some work for you:

```rb
<%= turbo_frame_tag :results, data: {controller: :mystimulus} %>
```

It's best to have a matching `turbo-frame` at the request location, but this works too:

```js
connect() {
  this.element.src = "/myurl.turbo_stream"
}
```

Just don't overdo it:

```js
connect() {
  this.element.loaded
    .then(() => {
      this.element.src = "/items/1.turbo_stream";
      return this.element.loaded;
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.element.src = "/items/2.turbo_stream";
      return this.element.loaded;
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.element.src = "/items/3.turbo_stream";
    });
}
```

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/frames#properties*

Answer (score 0):

There is no plan to add an after-stream-render event. See the following discussion: https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/event-to-know-a-turbo-stream-has-been-rendered/1554/18.

To solve that with vanilla JavaScript, see https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/event-to-know-a-turbo-stream-has-been-rendered/1554/18 and examples in https://javascript.info/mutation-observer#dynamic-highlight-demo to observe and execute code on any changes in a DOM element.

```
let observer = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => {
  console.log(mutationRecords); // console.log(the changes)
  // execute your code here.
});
  
let elem = document.getElementById("div-id");
    
// observe everything except attributes
observer.observe(elem, {
  childList: true, // observe direct children
  subtree: true, // and lower descendants too
  characterDataOldValue: true // pass old data to callback
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this feature was at the moment you wrote your post. But today you can use targets' callbacks. Example from official documentation:

```
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "item" ]

  itemTargetConnected(element) {
    this.sortElements(this.itemTargets)
  }

  itemTargetDisconnected(element) {
    this.sortElements(this.itemTargets)
  }

  // Private
  sortElements(itemTargets) { /* ... */ }
}
```

https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/targets#connected-and-disconnected-callbacks