# Rails 7 + hotwire. Is it possible to turbo_replace form part not whole form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

I have no idea if is it possible to do.

I have form for company Profile. Some data (17 fields in company_data partial) can be fetch using tax_number. Is is possible to replace  turbo_frame  'profile_company_data' with controler turbo_stream.replace?

How to get **f** (form_builder object) in turbo_stream - it is needed to render partial in turbo response.

```
= form_with model: @profile, url: profile_path  do |f|
  .columns 
    .column.is-4
      .field
        =f.label :tax_number, 'Tax number', class: 'label is-required'
        .control 
          = f.text_field :tax_number, class: 'input', maxlength: "13"
    .column.is-2 
      .button.is-primary{onClick -> 'fetch_company_data()'} Read company Data
  = turbo_frame_tag 'profile_company_data' do
    = render 'company_data', f: f

  .block
    = f.fields_for :main_address do |addr|
      = render 'address_fields', f: addr
```

I've tried render this snippet inside turbo response. It works but it creates nested form tag with new csrf-token.

```
= form_with model: @profile, url: profile_path  do |f|
  = render 'company_data', f: f
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fields` method instead of `form_with`

```
def add_nested_field
  @profile = current_user.profile
end

// add_nested_field.turbo_stream.erb
<%= turbo_stream.update("profile_company_data") do %>
  <%= fields model: @profile do |f| %>
    <%= render 'company_data', f: f %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will generate the fields with correct naming for params but not add the csrf token, etc.. that form_with does.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it straight from controller:

```rb
def something
  # TODO: @profile =

  respond_to do |format|
    format.turbo_stream do
      helpers.fields model: @profile do |f|
        render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update(
          :profile_company_data, partial: "company_data", locals: {f:}
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`onClick -> 'fetch_company_data()'` that will need to be a *TURBO_STREAM* request: *https://stackoverflow.com/a/75579188/207090*

Do you actually need `turbo_frame_tag` there?

Note that `replace` will **replace** the `<turbo-frame>` with whatever is rendered by the partial. But you probably want to keep it.